# Fire up a function if there is no RPM being detected off the Infra red sensor

Tags: pi-3, python, rpi.gpio, sensor

The code prints the rpm and keep on running after every 0.1 seconds.

What I am trying to do is call another function if there is no rpm printed on the screen for 10 seconds (that means when the rpm is 0 I want to call another function and the script still keeps running.)

```py
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time

sensor = 21 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN) 

sample = 1000 

count = 0

start = 0

end = 0

def set_start():

    global start
    start = time.time()

def set_end():

    global end
    end = time.time()

def get_rpm(c):

    global count 

    if not count:
        set_start() 
        count = count + 1 
    else:
        count = count + 1
    if count==sample:

        set_end() 
        delta = end - start 
        delta = delta / 60 
        rpm = (sample / delta) / 2 
        print rpm
        count = 0 

GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.RISING, callback=get_rpm) 

try:

    while True: 
        time.sleep(0.1)

    except KeyboardInterrupt:

    print "  Quit"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, in fact you need to track when your "rpm printing" function was launched, storing this event time in a variable (let's call it `lastTimeEvent`), and continnually check this variable in your while loop.

```
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO
import time
lastTimeEvent=None
sensor = 21 

GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)

GPIO.setup(sensor,GPIO.IN) 

sample = 1000 

count = 0

start = 0

end = 0

def set_start():

    global start
    start = time.time()

def set_end():

    global end
    end = time.time()

def get_rpm(c):

    global count, lastTimeEvent

    if not count:
        set_start() 
        count = count + 1 
    else:
        count = count + 1
    if count==sample:
        lastTimeEvent=time.time()
        set_end() 
        delta = end - start 
        delta = delta / 60 
        rpm = (sample / delta) / 2 
        print rpm
        count = 0 

GPIO.add_event_detect(sensor, GPIO.RISING, callback=get_rpm) 

try:
    while True:             
        if lastTimeEvent is not None:
            if time.time()-lastTimeEvent>10:
                MySpecificFunction()
                lastTimeEvent=None #resetting this variable prevent the function to be continnually called
        time.sleep(0.1)

except KeyboardInterrupt:

    print "  Quit"
    GPIO.cleanup()
```

Passing this `lastTimeEvent` variable to None at the program initialisation and at each specificFunction() call prevent your program to trigger this specific function at boot or multiple time.